# ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure When Using UTL_HTTP.REQUEST in Autonomous Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

When I execute the following statement that involves a UTL_HTTP.REQUEST call, I get **ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure**:

```
SELECT UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://www.google.com') from DUAL;

ORA-29273: HTTP request failed 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1620 
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1560 
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

According to the Autonomous Database doc, UTL_HTTP is among the supported PL/SQL packages. Why is this query not working?

Answer (score 1):

This error is a result of not completing the prerequisite steps for UTL_HTTP in Autonomous Database. As mentioned in [the example from the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-database-pl-sql-packages-restrictions.html#GUID-829A7D07-1EA4-4F59-AA60-F780FABAFDEC), before calling the UTL_HTTP.REQUEST() procedure, we need to first create an Access Control List (ACL) for the host via the DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE() and set the wallet location via UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET():

```
-- Create an Access Control List for the host
BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
         host => 'www.google.com',
         ace =>  xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('http'),
                             principal_name => 'ADMIN',
                             principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

-- Set Oracle Wallet location (no arguments needed)
BEGIN
   UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('');
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SELECT UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://www.google.com') from DUAL;

utl_http.request('https://www.google.com')
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"> ...
```

Disclaimer: I’m a Product Manager at Oracle.